# Salesforce CLI - How to disable warnings?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, cli, warning

Since the last Salesforce CLI Update 7.193.2 I've been seeing this warnings in the "Problems" tab in Visual Studio Code.

Does anyone know how to disable them?
It makes my code unreadable, since every SOQL query is marked by it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the root cause.
Apex PMD Extension was throwing those warnings.